# Ionic Vue: this.$router.push('/home) changes link but renders same page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, ionic6

I am trying to push to home page after login. When used:

```
this.$router.push()
```

url changes from

> localhost:8100/auth/login

to

> localhost:8100/home

but page remains same i.e. Login Page.

My Routes index file is as:

```
const routes:Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
 {
   path:'/',
   redirect:'/home
 },{
    path:'/home',
    component: ()=>import('@/views/HomePage.vue')
 },{
     path:'/auth/login',
     component: ()=>import('@/views/auth/LoginPage.vue')
 }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history:createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})
```

what can be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution...

I had not use ion-page tag on template of DashboardPage.vue. After adding ion-page tag, problem was resolved